# Find the Least Common Multiple (LCM) of exactly N-1 numbers chosen among N numbers

Tags: java, algorithm

Find the smallest number M, which is divided by exactly n-1 numbers from the input array. If there is no such M then return -1.

**Example:**

```
array = [2,3,5]
```

**Answer :**

```
6
```

**Explanation :**

```
6 can be divided by 2 and 3
```

**Example:**

```
array = [2,3,6]
```

**Answer:**

```
 -1
```

**Explanation :**

```
It's not possible in this case so return -1.
```

My code:

As we need to find the smallest `M`, I am selecting only the elements from 0 to n-2

```
public int process(int[] arr) {
    int answer = 1;
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length-1; i++) {
        answer *= arr[i];
    }
    return answer;
}
```

This program works for these 2 sample test cases but it was failing for multiple hidden test cases. I trying to understand what I am missing here.

Comment: You are multiplying together all but the last element in the given array in the order they are given to you. what if the example array you have is passed `[5, 3, 2]`?  what if you are given `[2, 3, 5, 6]`?

Comment: @user16320675 must be divisible by exactly n - 1, 6 is also divisible by 6

Comment: You question has generated some confusion.  Please include more specific examples with explanations as to why they match/don't match the criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start by writing a method `process` that computes the minimum number for each subarray with one element excluded:

```
public static int process(int... arr) {
    int min = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        int r = process(arr, i);
        if (r != -1) {
            if (min == -1) {
                min = r;
            } else {
                min = Math.min(min, r);
            }
        }
    }
    return min;
}
```

Where the second `process` method looks like this:

```
private static int process(int[] arr, int exclude) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        if (i != exclude) {
            if (result == 0) {
                result = arr[i];
            } else {
                result = lcm(result, arr[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    if (result%arr[exclude] == 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

You need a method that computes the LCM of two numbers. Here, I'll use a second method that computes the GCD:

```
private static int lcm(int a, int b) {
    return a*b/gcd(a,b);
}


private static int gcd(int a, int b) {
    if (a == 0) {
        return b;
    } else if (b == 0) {
        return a;
    } else {
        while (a != b) {
            if (a > b) {
                a -= b;
            } else {
                b -= a;
            }
        }
        return a;
    }
}
```

Examples:

```
    System.out.println(process(2, 3, 5)); // prints 6
    System.out.println(process(2, 3, 6)); // prints -1
    System.out.println(process(9, 14, 21)); // prints 42 (divisible by 14 and 21, but not by 9
    System.out.println(process(6, 7, 5, 3)); // prints 30 (divisible by 6, 5, 3, but not by 7
```

Answer (score 2):

### Calculation of the Least Common Multiple (LCM)

A problem inside the task is the calculation of the Least Common Multiple of 2 numbers. The method `public int lowerCommonMultiple(int x1, int x2)` solves this problem and I think it can be used in other context.

### List of the class methods

All the code is included in the methods of the `BestMultiple` class. These methods (excluding the `main`) are:

- `public int[] removeElem(int[] tensArray, int rm_index)`: used to remove an element from an array
- `public int leastCommonMultiple(int x1, int x2)`: calculates the Least Common Multiple of 2 numbers
- `private int getLeastCommonMultipleNnumber(int[] arr)`: Calculates the least common  multiple of N-1 integer contain in an array
- `public int process(int[] arr)`: calculates the least multiple of exactly N-1 number of an array of N integer; it manages many test strange cases (array empty, elem<=0, etc.)

May be the code is not optimized, but I hope it is correct (the output added, shows that it works correctly, at least with the test cases chosen).

```
public class BestMultiple {

    /*++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
      Method: removeElem() remove an element from
              an array.
     +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++*/
    public int[] removeElem(int[] tensArray, int rm_index) {
        // Create a proxy array of size one less than original array
        int[] proxyArray = new int[tensArray.length - 1];
        // copy all the elements in the original to proxy array
        // except the one at index
        for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < tensArray.length; i++) {
            // check if index is crossed, continue without copying
            if (i == rm_index) {
                continue;
            }
            // else copy the element
            proxyArray[k++] = tensArray[i];
        }

        return proxyArray;
    }

    /*+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
      Method: leastCommonMultiple() Calculates the Least Common
              multiple for 2 numbers
     ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++*/
    public int leastCommonMultiple(int x1, int x2) {
        int lcm = 1;
        int max = x1;
        if ((x1 == 0) || (x2 == 0)) {
            lcm = 0;
        } else {
            if (x2 > x1) {
                max = x2;
            }
            for (int i = 2; i <= max; i++) {
                int exp_x1 = 0;
                int exp_x2 = 0;
                int exp = 0;
                if (x1 > 1) {
                    while ((x1 % i) == 0) {
                        exp_x1++;
                        x1 /= i;
                    }
                }
                if (x2 > 1) {
                    while ((x2 % i) == 0) {
                        exp_x2++;
                        x2 /= i;
                    }
                }
                if ((exp_x1 > 0) || (exp_x2 > 0)) {
                    exp = exp_x1;
                    if (exp_x2 > exp) {
                        exp = exp_x2;
                    }
                    while (exp > 0) {
                        lcm *= i;
                        exp--;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return lcm;
    }
    
    /*+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    Method: getLeastCommonMultipleNnumber()
            Calculates the least common  multiple of N-1
            integer contain in an array
   +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++*/
    public int getLeastCommonMultipleNnumber(int[] arr) {
        int multiple = 1;
        if (arr.length >= 2) {
            multiple = leastCommonMultiple(arr[0], arr[1]);
            for (int j = 2; j < arr.length; j++) {
                multiple = leastCommonMultiple(multiple, arr[j]);
            }
        } else {
            // array with only 2 elements
            multiple = arr[0];
        }
        return multiple;
    }

    /*+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
      Method: process()
              Calculates the least multiple of EXACTLY N-1
              number of an array of N integer
     +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++*/
    public int process(int[] arr) {
        int answer;

        if (arr.length <= 1) {
            // array contains only one element or is empty => return -1
            answer = -1;
        } else {
            int pos_elem_zero = -1;
            int prod = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if (arr[i] > 0) {
                    prod *= arr[i];
                } else {
                    if (arr[i] < 0) {
                        // integer < 0 are not allowed
                        return -1;
                    }
                    if (pos_elem_zero == -1) {
                        pos_elem_zero = i;
                    } else {
                        // there are more element == 0
                        return -1;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (pos_elem_zero >= 0) {
                // there is one element == 0 
                arr = this.removeElem(arr, pos_elem_zero);
                return getLeastCommonMultipleNnumber(arr);
            }

            // managing of normal test case
            answer = prod;
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                int elem = arr[i];
                int[] arr2 = this.removeElem(arr, i);
                int multiple = getLeastCommonMultipleNnumber(arr2);
                if (multiple > elem) {
                    if ((multiple % elem) != 0) {
                        if (multiple < answer) {
                            answer = multiple;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if (multiple < elem) {
                        answer = multiple;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (answer == prod) {
                answer = -1;
            }
        }
        return answer;
    }

    /*++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
      Method: main() Executes test of process()
              method
     +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++*/
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BestMultiple bm = new BestMultiple();
        int[] arr1 = {6,30,5,3};
        int[] arr2 = {1,2,3};
        int[] arr3 = {1,2,3,3};
        int[] arr4 = {6,7,5,3};
        int[] arr5 = {9,14, 21};
        int[] arr6 = {2,4};
        int[] arr7 = {2,3,5};
        int[] arr8 = {2,3,6};
        int[] arr9 = {2};
        int[] arr10 = {};
        int[] arr11 = {2,3,0};
        int[] arr12 = {0,2,3,0};
        int[] arr13 = {20,3};
        int[] arr14 = {0,6,15};
        int[] arr15 = {1,6,15,-1};
        int[] arr16 = {1,6,15};
        int[] arr17 = {2,3,0,6,15};        

        System.out.println("{6,30,5,3} --> " + bm.process(arr1));
        System.out.println("{1,2,3} --> " + bm.process(arr2));
        System.out.println("{1,2,3,3} --> " + bm.process(arr3));
        System.out.println("{6,7,5,3} --> " + bm.process(arr4));
        System.out.println("{9,14,21} --> " + bm.process(arr5));
        System.out.println("{2,4} --> " + bm.process(arr6));
        System.out.println("{2,3,5} --> " + bm.process(arr7));
        System.out.println("{2,3,6} --> " + bm.process(arr8));
        System.out.println("{2} --> " + bm.process(arr9));
        System.out.println("{} --> " + bm.process(arr10));
        System.out.println("{2,3,0} --> " + bm.process(arr11));
        System.out.println("{0,2,3,0} --> " + bm.process(arr12));
        System.out.println("{20,3} --> " + bm.process(arr13));
        System.out.println("{0,6,15} --> " + bm.process(arr14));
        System.out.println("{1,6,15,-1} --> " + bm.process(arr15));
        System.out.println("{1,6,15} --> " + bm.process(arr16));
        System.out.println("{2,3,0,6,15} --> " + bm.process(arr17));
    }
}
```

### Output of the program

The output of the program with the test cases chosen is:

```
{6,30,5,3} --> -1
{1,2,3} --> 2
{1,2,3,3} --> 3
{6,7,5,3} --> 30
{9,14,21} --> 42
{2,4} --> 2
{2,3,5} --> 6
{2,3,6} --> -1
{2} --> -1
{} --> -1
{2,3,0} --> 6
{0,2,3,0} --> -1
{20,3} --> 3
{0,6,15} --> 30
{1,6,15,-1} --> -1
{1,6,15} --> 6
{2,3,0,6,15} --> 30
```

Comment: Not sure this works. Say you have `[2, 3, 5, 6]` I believe your code would return `-1` however I don't see why `6` wouldn't be the answer here

Comment: @frankfalse you're right, my mistake. however your solution is still incorrect

Comment: Counterexample: `[9, 14, 21]`. The three possible answers are `9*14=126`, `9*21=189`, or `14*21=294`. Your code would generate 126, and then return -1 because 126 is divisible by 21. The actual answer is 189 because it's not divisible by 14.

Comment: In your own example `[6, 7, 5, 3]` 90 is incorrect. 30 is lower and divisable by 3, 5, and 6 but not 7

Comment: @user16320675 Good catch. I forgot the LCM step. So the answer is 42, which is not divisible by 9, but is divisible by 14 and 21.

Comment: @user3386109  42 !! what else

Comment: @user16320675 :)

Comment: The problem were not so easy how I was thinking. Thanks for your test cases.

Comment: Ok, I don't understand why `{1,2,3,3} --> 3` is correct.   3 can be divided by 1,3,and, 3 which supports the divisibility by `n-1` numbers when `n is 4`.  But 3 is also divisible by just `3` which would indicate that -1 should be returned (as per the example in the question.)

Comment: @WJS In the case of `{1,2,3,3}` I suppose that the n-1 numbers are {1,3,3} so their LCM is 3 and the number `2` is the excluded number of the array.

Answer (score 0):

The way you implemented `process()` assumes the input array is sorted. But anyway, I don't think sorting will help here. Note that the number satisfying the given conditions can be divided by the biggest number. For `[2, 3, 5, 6]` it is `6`. Dividing the product of all the elements by consecutive elements from the biggest to the lowest and stopping at the first that is not a divisor is also not correct. In the example `[2, 4, 5, 6]` this would give `2 * 4 * 5 = 40` when the correct answer is `20`.

My idea is to use an algorithm inspired by [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). Note that the number that satisfies the conditions can't be bigger than the product of all the elements. So create a table `divisors[]` with indices from 0 through the product of the elements of `array` where `divisors[i]` indicates how many elements from `array` divide `i`. Iterate over elements of `array` and increment all elements in `divisors[i]` where `i` is divided by the element. Then find the first `i` for which `divisors[i] == n - 1`.

The limitation is that `divisors` can be quite big depending on what is the product of `array`, so applicability will be limited to relatively small values in `array`.